# Retrieving data from a 2 columns UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I implemented a UIPickerView with 2 columns and I would like to retrieve the first column value and set to a minutesDuration value of double type and retrieve another double value named secondsDuration from the second column. Then transform the minutes to seconds and add the two values together in a double value named totalDuration.
Here's my didSelectRow method:

```
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *minute =[[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *seconds = [[NSString alloc] init];

    //Here, like the table view you can get the each section of each row if you've multiple sections
    if(component == 0){
        int i =row;
        int j =row;

            minute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [minutesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            seconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [secondsArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            double minutesDuration = [minute doubleValue] * 60;
            NSLog(@"%f", minutesDuration);
            double secondsDuration = [seconds doubleValue];
            totalDuration = minutesDuration + secondsDuration;
            NSLog(@"%f", totalDuration);
    }
    else if (component == 1){
        int i =0;
        int j =row;
        minute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [minutesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        seconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [secondsArray objectAtIndex:j]];
        double minutesDuration = [minute doubleValue] * 60;
        NSLog(@"%f", minutesDuration);
        double secondsDuration = [seconds doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%f", secondsDuration);
        totalDuration = minutesDuration + secondsDuration;
        NSLog(@"%f", totalDuration);
    }
}
```

When I run the app 1 of 2 main appear:
- The values aren't added
- The two values are added even if the second column value isn't changed
Btw the total duration is declared in the header file.

Comment: Instead it use UIDatepicker with `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer ` mode...

Comment: Can you send me a link of a tutorial for it?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative:**

You can use the countDownDuration property in `UIDatePicker` when the date picker mode is set to `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`.The countdown duration is in seconds.

**.h**

```
@interface ThisPicker : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

**.m**

```
viewdidLoad
{
   datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    dp.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;

    [self.view addSubview:dp];

}
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
  {

   NSLog(@"time in seconds: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",datePicker.countDownDuration] );


  }
```